Uncaught SyntaxError ':' in Chrome Extension (TypeScript is not being properly recognized)
I'm developing a Chrome extension using Vue 3 and Vite. My extension includes a background script written in TypeScript.
However, I'm encountering two issues:

Service Worker Registration Failed: The service worker registration fails with status code 15.
Uncaught SyntaxError: I get an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' error in my background.ts file.

It seems like TypeScript is not being properly recognized or transpiled.
Here are the details of my setup:
background.ts:
// Create a context menu item for the extension
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: "name",
  title: "title",
  contexts: ["selection"],
});

let selectedLanguages: { code: string; name: string; charset: string[] }[] = [];

main.ts
import { createApp } from "vue";
import "./style.css";
import App from "./App.vue";
import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";

import "primevue/resources/themes/aura-light-purple/theme.css";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(PrimeVue, {
  /* options */
});
app.mount("#app");

App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import Popup from "./components/Popup.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <Popup />
</template>

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}

manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "This is a description",
  "author": "",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "/src/components/scripts/background.ts"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["/src/components/scripts/content.ts"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "storage"]
}

Issues:

Service Worker Registration Failed: The error message is Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15.

Uncaught SyntaxError: The error message is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' at http://localhost:5173//src/components/scripts/background.ts:8.


What I've Tried:

Verified the file paths in manifest.json.
Ensured that TypeScript is correctly configured in tsconfig.json.
Checked for syntax errors in background.ts.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Browsers can't run typescript directly, so you have to compile the source files and make sure your compiler produces manifest.json with the compiled js files, not ts.

do you have any reference on how to make that? @woxxom
